# How to programmatically configure proxy in Azure SDK for C++

Tags: c++, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-sdk

How to programmatically configure Azure SDK for C++ (https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-cpp/index.html) to use a specific proxy?

When using older package **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CPP.v140** I could use the following code to accomplish it:

```
azure::storage::operation_context::set_default_proxy(web::web_proxy(proxyAddress));
```

However, I cannot find a corresponding way of doing it in the new package.
Is this even possible in the new package?

Comment: You mean [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CPP) untouched since 2018?

Comment: @Botje I made a mistake in my original post. It's been updated.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!